# Merge two properties to Entity Framework entity with partial class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I'm using Entity Framework.

My `Customer` Entity is:

```
public partial class Customer
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a `BaseEntity` class which is inherited by partial `Customer` class.

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
}

public partial class Customer : BaseEntity
{

}
```

After that, I created a generic method as follows:

```
public static int GetId<T>(T entity) where T : BaseEntity
{
    // id is zero after savechanges
    var id = entity.ID;
    return id;
}
```

My problem occurs when I want to get the id after `SaveChanges()` in the generic method, it's zero.

My test code is:

```
var db = new ContextDb();

db.Customers.Add(customer);
db.SaveChanges();

WriteLine($@"{customer.ID}"); // OK
WriteLine($@"{GetId(customer)}"); // Not OK --> ZERO
```

Thanks everyone for taking the time to try and help explain.

Comment: Is there design a reason for why you are making these properties all virtual? I think that practice is misleading you here in the first place. If it's specifically to support Lazy loading, you only need to make navigational properties virtual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is caused by the fact that, indeed, you have two `ID` fields: one (hidden) from `BaseEntity` (which has a value of zero) and one from `Customer` (which is not zero). Try to `override` the `ID` property or simply remove it from the `Customer` class declaration:

```
public partial class Customer
{
    public override int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

You can also mark the `ID` property and `BaseEntity` class as `abstract` to force to `override` the `ID` property in inherited classes:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public abstract int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> NOTE: Previously accepted answer is not good advice, while it satisfies the issue, for new developers it encourages them to think that it is normal to make all properties virtual or common practice to override every virtual member from the base class.

Because `BaseEntity` already defines ID, you *SHOULD NOT* be trying to re-implement ID in the inheriting class unless you specifically want to augment the original implementation.

- In this case we are not offering any different implementation to the base and so should not be trying to override it.

Conversely, if you **do** want to force *every* inheriting class to implement a function or property in their own way, [then mark it as abstract, not virtual, and follow this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51035496/1690217).

Putting all 3 class definitions in-line, I would recommend the following solution:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
public partial class Customer : BaseEntity
{

}
public partial class Customer
{
    // ID is provided from the base!
    //public int ID { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

Using `virtual` properties becomes dangerous as a design choice because there is a gray area where [auto-properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties) might or might not be implemented in the base or other inheriting classes. If all classes in the inheritance tree use auto-properties, then there is no issue, however when any traditional getter or setter that is not *auto* is overriden, if the override does not call back to the base implementation, then any references to the fields or placeholders that were implemented in the base will not have their values set.

- which is pretty close to the situation that OP has raised.

> Specifically with ORM tools like EF, I would caution making the ID property virtual or abstract at all.
>
> > The ID is too important to leave to chance.
> >
> > If you are using virtual properties to support Lazy Loading, in EF you only need to make navigational properties virtual to support this, not every property on a class.